# Messed up file contents in vagrant smb shared file

Tags: vagrant, homestead, smb, docker-for-windows, docker

I decided to throw up a quick OpenCart installation today using the Homestead vagrant box with Hyper-V on my Windows 10 machine, and I've got my opencart folder mapped like this in Homestead.yml:

```
- map: D:\web\www\oc\oc-3.0.2.0
  to: /home/vagrant/code/opencart
  type: "smb"
```

All's well. The folder is synced in the vagrant VM as expected. But on trying to install OpenCart, I get this parse error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''] == '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/vagrant/code/opencart/upload/system/startup.php on line 93
```

Looking at lines 92-94 of that file on my host machine:

```
require_once(modification(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/event.php'));
require_once(modification(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/router.php'));
require_once(modification(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/loader.php'));
```

Looking at the same lines on the synced file in vagrant:

```
 require_once(modification(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/event.php'));
 requirePROTO'] == 'https' || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on') {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = true;
```

This code that's replaced the "require_once" code here appears earlier in this file. It's as if it's recopied over later code, making this file unusable. [Here's the full file.](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/3.0.2.0/upload/system/startup.php)

If I delete the lines that are copied or replace them with some other code, things appear find in the vagrant version. But if I only delete a couple of the lines, the rest still overwrite later code.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this or how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this had nothing to do with Homestead nor OpenCart. I pulled up another vagrant project I had and noticed similar problems with synced files.

I had recently installed **Docker for Windows** to play around with, so I decided to uninstall it and see if that would fix the problem. And it did.

So somewhere, somehow Vagrant and Docker aren't getting along on Windows 10. No idea where the exact problem is, though.

Comment: I have got similar issues with vagrant and  SMB shared folders. Zip/Unzip doesn't seem to work in some cases and when editing files the written content looks different from what I was trying to save ...
The point is that I need to use docker in that VM and docker inside docker doesn't work properly